# Problem with log and home directories and roslaunch handlers

Tags: ros, robot-upstart

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having a problem `robot_upstart`.  When I start the service it uses a different value for `ROS_LOG_DIR`, it says that `HOME` is not defined, and also reports there are no handlers for `roslaunch`.  I've pasted a log below:

```
hal@arlobot:~/catkin_ws/src/ArloBot/src/arlobot_apps/arlobot_webif/www$ sudo tail /var/log/upstart/arlobot.log -f
[sudo] password for hal:
logger: arlobot: Using workspace setup file /home/hal/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
logger: arlobot: Launching ROS_HOSTNAME=arlobot, ROS_IP=, ROS_MASTER_URI=http://127.0.0.1:11311, ROS_LOG_DIR=/tmp
ls: cannot access /etc/ros/indigo/arlobot.d/*.xacro: No such file or directory
logger: arlobot: Generated launchfile: /tmp/arlobot.launch
logger: arlobot: Started roslaunch as background process, PID 9009, **ROS_LOG_DIR=/tmp
WARNING: cannot create log directory [/tmp/852af2b6-88a5-11e5-8d69-408d5c19117e]. Please set ROS_LOG_DIR to a writable location.**
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

logger: arlobot: Using workspace setup file /home/hal/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
logger: arlobot: Launching ROS_HOSTNAME=arlobot, ROS_IP=, ROS_MASTER_URI=http://127.0.0.1:11311, ROS_LOG_DIR=/tmp
ls: cannot access /etc/ros/indigo/arlobot.d/*.xacro: No such file or directory
logger: arlobot: Generated launchfile: /tmp/arlobot.launch
logger: arlobot: Started roslaunch as background process, PID 9146, ROS_LOG_DIR=/tmp
WARNING: cannot create log directory [/tmp/a7c12afe-88a8-11e5-88de-408d5c19117e]. Please set ROS_LOG_DIR to a writable location.
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

**No handlers could be found for logger "roslaunch"
environment variable 'HOME' is not set**
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
logger: arlobot: Using workspace setup file /home/hal/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
logger: arlobot: Launching ROS_HOSTNAME=arlobot, ROS_IP=, ROS_MASTER_URI=http://127.0.0.1:11311, ROS_LOG_DIR=/tmp
ls: cannot access /etc/ros/indigo/arlobot.d/*.xacro: No such file or directory
logger: arlobot: Generated launchfile: /tmp/arlobot.launch
logger: arlobot: Started roslaunch as background process, PID 9225, ROS_LOG_DIR=/tmp
WARNING: cannot create log directory [/tmp/a86bd620-88a8-11e5-9cab-408d5c19117e]. Please set ROS_LOG_DIR to a writable location.
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220780/problem-with-log-and-home-directories-and-roslaunch-handlers/) by [tslator](https://answers.ros.org/users/25073/tslator/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-11-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

May be a bit late but I had a similar error my upstart was working then it gave the above errors
I put in a extra launch line to start COB face recognition when i remove the line robot upstart worked as before

---

Originally posted by [Peter Heim](https://answers.ros.org/users/71/peter-heim/) with karma: 215 on 2016-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on 2016-08-17**:
Did you ever find a fix for this other than removing functionality. I am getting the same errors trying to start an openCV haar cascade filter on startup.

**Comment by [Peter Heim](https://answers.ros.org/users/71/peter-heim/) on 2016-08-18**:
no I never fixed the cause I just start it manually when required